# calculate moving avg in Oracle and show the periods

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to calculate a 10 period moving avg in Oracle SQL but can't seem to get it right.

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT
          BSM_ID
          ,CASE
                WHEN D_DTM = (SELECT MAX(D_DTM)-10/24 FROM DMSN.DS3R_FH_1XRTT_BTS_LVL_KPI) 
                THEN (CASE WHEN sum(V_ATT_CNT) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE sum(V_CUST_BLK_CNT)/sum(V_ATT_CNT) END) 
                END AS "PERIOD1"
          ,CASE
                WHEN D_DTM = (SELECT MAX(D_DTM)-9/24 FROM DMSN.DS3R_FH_1XRTT_BTS_LVL_KPI) 
                THEN (CASE WHEN sum(V_ATT_CNT) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE sum(V_CUST_BLK_CNT)/sum(V_ATT_CNT) END) 
                END AS "PERIOD2"
          ,CASE
                WHEN D_DTM = (SELECT MAX(D_DTM)-8/24 FROM DMSN.DS3R_FH_1XRTT_BTS_LVL_KPI) 
                THEN (CASE WHEN sum(V_ATT_CNT) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE sum(V_CUST_BLK_CNT)/sum(V_ATT_CNT) END) 
                END AS "PERIOD3"
          ,CASE
                WHEN D_DTM = (SELECT MAX(D_DTM)-7/24 FROM DMSN.DS3R_FH_1XRTT_BTS_LVL_KPI) 
                THEN (CASE WHEN sum(V_ATT_CNT) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE sum(V_CUST_BLK_CNT)/sum(V_ATT_CNT) END) 
                END AS "PERIOD4"           
          ,CASE
                WHEN D_DTM = (SELECT MAX(D_DTM)-6/24 FROM DMSN.DS3R_FH_1XRTT_BTS_LVL_KPI) 
                THEN (CASE WHEN sum(V_ATT_CNT) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE sum(V_CUST_BLK_CNT)/sum(V_ATT_CNT) END) 
                END AS "PERIOD5"           
          ,CASE
                WHEN D_DTM = (SELECT MAX(D_DTM)-5/24 FROM DMSN.DS3R_FH_1XRTT_BTS_LVL_KPI) 
                THEN (CASE WHEN sum(V_ATT_CNT) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE sum(V_CUST_BLK_CNT)/sum(V_ATT_CNT) END) 
                END AS "PERIOD6"            
          ,CASE
                WHEN D_DTM = (SELECT MAX(D_DTM)-4/24 FROM DMSN.DS3R_FH_1XRTT_BTS_LVL_KPI) 
                THEN (CASE WHEN sum(V_ATT_CNT) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE sum(V_CUST_BLK_CNT)/sum(V_ATT_CNT) END) 
                END AS "PERIOD7"            
          ,CASE
                WHEN D_DTM = (SELECT MAX(D_DTM)-3/24 FROM DMSN.DS3R_FH_1XRTT_BTS_LVL_KPI) 
                THEN (CASE WHEN sum(V_ATT_CNT) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE sum(V_CUST_BLK_CNT)/sum(V_ATT_CNT) END) 
                END AS "PERIOD8"    
          ,CASE
                WHEN D_DTM = (SELECT MAX(D_DTM)-2/24 FROM DMSN.DS3R_FH_1XRTT_BTS_LVL_KPI) 
                THEN (CASE WHEN sum(V_ATT_CNT) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE sum(V_CUST_BLK_CNT)/sum(V_ATT_CNT) END) 
                END AS "PERIOD9"            
          ,CASE
                WHEN D_DTM = (SELECT MAX(D_DTM)-1/24 FROM DMSN.DS3R_FH_1XRTT_BTS_LVL_KPI) 
                THEN (CASE WHEN sum(V_ATT_CNT) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE sum(V_CUST_BLK_CNT)/sum(V_ATT_CNT) END) 
                END AS "PERIOD10"            
          ,AVG(
                CASE
                WHEN D_DTM BETWEEN (SELECT MAX(D_DTM)-1/24 FROM DMSN.DS3R_FH_1XRTT_BTS_LVL_KPI) AND (SELECT MAX(D_DTM)-10/24 FROM DMSN.DS3R_FH_1XRTT_BTS_LVL_KPI) 
                THEN (CASE WHEN sum(V_ATT_CNT) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE sum(V_CUST_BLK_CNT)/sum(V_ATT_CNT) END) 
                END
              ) AS "10 PERIOD AVG" 

    FROM DMSN.DS3R_FH_1XRTT_BTS_LVL_KPI
    where D_DTM >= (SELECT MAX(D_DTM)-10/24 FROM DMSN.DS3R_FH_1XRTT_BTS_LVL_KPI) 

    GROUP BY
          BSM_ID
    order by BSM_ID desc
```

But keep getting a "not a single-group group function" error. What I'm trying to do is show the % for each of the 10 periods by columns, and then have the 11th column as the AVG. I remember doing something similar in SQL but I can't get the syntanx right here in PLSQL

in SQL server I was able to do this to achieve the same result:

```
  SELECT         carrier,
             dIVISION,
             LOcATION,
             servicetype
             ,max(@maxwk-1) as ops_week_id
             ,max(case when ops_week_id = @maxwk-2 then (OT * 100.00) / ts else null end)
               as [%_wk_1 ] 
             ,max(case when ops_week_id = @maxwk-3 then (OT * 100.00) / ts else null end)
               as [%_wk_2 ]   
             ,max(case when ops_week_id = @maxwk-4 then (OT * 100.00) / ts else null end)
               as [%_wk_3 ]
             ,max(case when ops_week_id = @maxwk-5 then (OT * 100.00) / ts else null end)
               as [%_wk_4 ]
             ,avg(case when ops_week_id Between @maxwk-5 and @maxwk - 2  then (OT * 100.00) / ts else null end)
               as [4_wk_SMA]
             ,avg(case when ops_week_id Between @maxwk-5 and @maxwk - 2  then (OT * 100.00) / ts else null end)
               - 0.15 as [LwrBand]            
             ,avg(case when ops_week_id Between @maxwk-5 and @maxwk - 2  then (OT * 100.00) / ts else null end)
               + 0.15 as [UprBand]  
             ,max(case when ops_week_id = @maxwk-1 then (OT * 100.00) / ts else null end)
               as [Ops_wk_id_av] 
         FROM la

       GROUP BY la.DIVISION,la.LOCATION,la.servicetype,la.carrier
```

the Original table structure looks as such:

```
     D_DTM (datetime)
     F_ID
     REG_DTM
     MRKT_ID
     MRKT_NM
     CL_ID
     CL_NM
     BSM_ID
     BSM_NM
     BSC_SEQ_ID
     CSCD_ID
     CSCD_NM
     BTS_ID
     V_ATT_CNT (denominator)
     V_MBL_ORG_CNT
     V_MBL_TER_CNT
     V_SILENT_RETRY_CNT
     V_CUST_BLK_CNT (numerator)
```

What I want to do is take the percentage (V_CUST_BLK_CNT/V_ATT_CNT) for the last 10 hours, and then avg them by BSM_ID. So the resulting query for have a structure as such

BSM_ID | PERIOD1% | PERIOD2% | PERIOD3% | etc... | AVG%

I feel like I should be able to use case whens to do this but can't seem to get the group by and syntax to work...

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because you are grouping by `bsm_id`, but referencing many other columns without aggregate functions.

If you are using Oracle, then use the built-in functions for moving average.  These are the analytic functions with the `range` keyword, something like:

```
select bsm.*,
       (sum(V_CUST_BLK_CNT) over (partition by bsm_id order by d_dtm range between 10 preceding and current row) /
       (sum(V_CUST_ATT_CNT) over (partition by bsm_id order by d_dtm range between 10 preceding and current row))
from bsm
```

Comment: I'm not sure if thats exatcly what I'm looking for. The results are coming back with many repetitive rows of data. Also, how would I show what the actual values were for those 10 periods in columns like the above query.

Comment: @user2061886 . . . You would use the `lag()` function.  You need to study up on analytic functions, by looking at sites like and http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm http://www.orafaq.com/node/55.

Comment: I'm fairly new to the oracle env and this seems more challenging then sql evn is. why can't I just use case statements like above in oracle? seemed to work find in sql...

Comment: @user2061886: what do you mean with "works fine in sql"? All the queries discussed here are SQL.

Comment: @user2061886 . . . It would work much more efficiently with the proper use of window/analytic functions.  As a boost, these are also supported in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: so how would I write the one I've used in tsql in plsql? plsql just seems more confusing then tsql...sorry for the ignorance, but I'm very new to plsql

Answer (score 0):

ok, so I got my query to work like this:

```
SELECT 
    BSM_ID
    ,MAX(PERIOD1) AS "PERIOD1"
    ,MAX(PERIOD2) AS "PERIOD2"
    ,MAX(PERIOD3) AS "PERIOD3"
    ,MAX(PERIOD4) AS "PERIOD4"
    ,MAX(PERIOD5) AS "PERIOD5"
    ,MAX(PERIOD6) AS "PERIOD6"
    ,MAX(PERIOD7) AS "PERIOD7"
    ,MAX(PERIOD8) AS "PERIOD8"
    ,MAX(PERIOD9) AS "PERIOD9"
    ,MAX(PERIOD10) AS "PERIOD10"
    ,(MAX(PERIOD1)+MAX(PERIOD2)+MAX(PERIOD3)+MAX(PERIOD4)+MAX(PERIOD5)+MAX(PERIOD6)+MAX(PERIOD7)+MAX(PERIOD8)+MAX(PERIOD9)+MAX(PERIOD10))/10 AS "AVG"

    FROM
           (

            SELECT
                  BSM_ID
                  ,CASE
                        WHEN D_DTM = (SELECT MAX(D_DTM)-10/24 FROM DMSN.DS3R_FH_1XRTT_BTS_LVL_KPI) 
                        THEN (CASE WHEN sum(V_ATT_CNT) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE sum(V_CUST_BLK_CNT)/sum(V_ATT_CNT) END) 
                        END AS "PERIOD1"
                  ,CASE
                        WHEN D_DTM = (SELECT MAX(D_DTM)-9/24 FROM DMSN.DS3R_FH_1XRTT_BTS_LVL_KPI) 
                        THEN (CASE WHEN sum(V_ATT_CNT) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE sum(V_CUST_BLK_CNT)/sum(V_ATT_CNT) END) 
                        END AS "PERIOD2"
                  ,CASE
                        WHEN D_DTM = (SELECT MAX(D_DTM)-8/24 FROM DMSN.DS3R_FH_1XRTT_BTS_LVL_KPI) 
                        THEN (CASE WHEN sum(V_ATT_CNT) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE sum(V_CUST_BLK_CNT)/sum(V_ATT_CNT) END)
                        END AS "PERIOD3"
                  ,CASE
                        WHEN D_DTM = (SELECT MAX(D_DTM)-7/24 FROM DMSN.DS3R_FH_1XRTT_BTS_LVL_KPI) 
                        THEN (CASE WHEN sum(V_ATT_CNT) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE sum(V_CUST_BLK_CNT)/sum(V_ATT_CNT) END)
                        END AS "PERIOD4"           
                  ,CASE
                        WHEN D_DTM = (SELECT MAX(D_DTM)-6/24 FROM DMSN.DS3R_FH_1XRTT_BTS_LVL_KPI) 
                        THEN (CASE WHEN sum(V_ATT_CNT) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE sum(V_CUST_BLK_CNT)/sum(V_ATT_CNT) END)
                        END AS "PERIOD5"           
                  ,CASE
                        WHEN D_DTM = (SELECT MAX(D_DTM)-5/24 FROM DMSN.DS3R_FH_1XRTT_BTS_LVL_KPI) 
                        THEN (CASE WHEN sum(V_ATT_CNT) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE sum(V_CUST_BLK_CNT)/sum(V_ATT_CNT) END) 
                        END AS "PERIOD6"            
                  ,CASE
                        WHEN D_DTM = (SELECT MAX(D_DTM)-4/24 FROM DMSN.DS3R_FH_1XRTT_BTS_LVL_KPI) 
                        THEN (CASE WHEN sum(V_ATT_CNT) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE sum(V_CUST_BLK_CNT)/sum(V_ATT_CNT) END) 
                        END AS "PERIOD7"            
                  ,CASE
                        WHEN D_DTM = (SELECT MAX(D_DTM)-3/24 FROM DMSN.DS3R_FH_1XRTT_BTS_LVL_KPI) 
                        THEN (CASE WHEN sum(V_ATT_CNT) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE sum(V_CUST_BLK_CNT)/sum(V_ATT_CNT) END) 
                        END AS "PERIOD8"    
                  ,CASE
                        WHEN D_DTM = (SELECT MAX(D_DTM)-2/24 FROM DMSN.DS3R_FH_1XRTT_BTS_LVL_KPI) 
                        THEN (CASE WHEN sum(V_ATT_CNT) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE sum(V_CUST_BLK_CNT)/sum(V_ATT_CNT) END) 
                        END AS "PERIOD9"            
                  ,CASE
                        WHEN D_DTM = (SELECT MAX(D_DTM)-1/24 FROM DMSN.DS3R_FH_1XRTT_BTS_LVL_KPI) 
                        THEN (CASE WHEN sum(V_ATT_CNT) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE sum(V_CUST_BLK_CNT)/sum(V_ATT_CNT) END) 
                        END AS "PERIOD10"            


            FROM DMSN.DS3R_FH_1XRTT_BTS_LVL_KPI

            WHERE D_DTM >=(SELECT MAX(D_DTM)-10/24 FROM DMSN.DS3R_FH_1XRTT_BTS_LVL_KPI)

            GROUP BY BSM_ID, D_DTM

            )
    GROUP BY
    BSM_ID
```

I'm sure there is a more efficient way to do this but this works.